# How can you write a function that accepts multiple types?

Tags: java, variables, function, types

I have a function that should work on int[] and on String[] now i have made the same function with a int parameter and an String parameter however if it has to go this way its a bit copy paste work and doesn't look very organized is there a way to solve this and put these 4 functions in 2?

```
    static public void print(String s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    static public void print(int s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    static public void printArray(String[] s)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
            print(s[i]);
    }

    static public void printArray(int[] s)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
            print(s[i]);
    }
```

Thanks
Matthy

Comment: If you really mean you're printing the arguments, why not just call Arrays.toString(s)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With autoboxing / autounboxing, you can do this:

```
public static void print(Object s) {
  System.out.println(s.toString());
}

public static <T> void printArray(T[] arr) {
  for (T t : arr) {
    print(t);
  }
}
```

The one drawback is that the argument to `printArray` must be an array of a reference type, but unlike the varargs solution this will work for any reference type.

**Edit**: regarding the varargs solution and @matthy's question about combining the two methods into one (ie generifying it), you could also do something like this:

```
static public <T> void print(T... ts) {
    for (T t : ts) {
      System.out.print(t + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

However, you still cannot call it on an array of primitives:

```
int[] x = { 1, 2 };
print(x);
```

Because Java takes `T` to be `int[]` and will execute the `toString` method of the array rather than iterate through the contents.  If you call it on an array of `Integer` or other reference type then it will work also.

Comment: Generics adds nothing here. It is equivalent to `public static void printArray(Object[] arr) {
  for (Object t : arr) {
    print(t);
  }
}`

Comment: Try `ts.tostring.split(",")` which guarantees parsing of primitives, doesn't it?

Answer (score 8):

```
static public void print(String...strings){
    for(String str : strings){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

static public void print(int...ints){
    for(int i : ints){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: i meanth the oposite like what danben said but this looks interesting too is it possible to combine these 2 method's so you have only one function?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Basic class java.lang.Object matches String as well as int, byte, ... (Autoboxing converts them to Integer, Byte and so on). The method `String.valueOf()` lets you create a string of these. (toString() is available too)

Answer (score 0):

Use Generics, if applicable to your code:

```
static <T> void printArray(T[] s)
{
    for (int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
        System.out.println(s[i]);
}
```

Comment: generics adds nothing here. it is the same as `static void printArray(Object[] s)`

Answer (score 0):

Combining the previous answers yield:

```
public class Test {

    static <T> void print(T... ts) {
        for (T t : ts)
            System.out.println(t);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String[] strArr = { "one", "two" };
        Integer[] intArr = { 3, 4 };
        String str = "five";
        int i = 6;

        print(strArr);
        print(intArr);
        print(str);
        print(i);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
one
two
3
4
five
6
```

Answer (score -3):

```
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        String name ="David";
        int age = 42;
        double score =15.9;
        char group = 'Z';
        System.out.println(group  + "\n" + name + " \n" + age + " \n" + score);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not to simply use different types in one method. This is really **not at all** an answer to the question!